# MS Access 2007 with linked SQL Server 2008 tables - query with Date() and Now() not working

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, ms-access-2007

MS Access 2007 with linked SQL Server 2008 tables - queries with Date() and Now() do not work in Access when the table is a linked table from SQL. Without going to manual date criteria i.e. between 01/01/2012 and 31/01/2012, is there any work around?

Comment: Have you tried a passthrough query using SQL Server syntax?

Comment: I have attempting to do a pass-through query. With the only condition is Between GetDate() And GetDate()-7. But receive error message - ODBC --call failed. ... Invalid object name '[tablename]'. (#208)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't know what `Date()` and `Now()` are. I think you are looking for syntax like [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) and [`GETDATE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx). If you post the query you're trying to run in Access, someone can probably help you translate it to an equivalent SQL Server query.

Comment: An example is - Between Now() And Now()-7. Have tried GetDate with no luck

Comment: Are you using a passthrough query?

Comment: Sorry not sure what a passthrough query is?

Comment: In this case, it is a query that runs on SQL Server with sql server syntax: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303968

Comment: What does "have tried" mean? What does "no luck" mean? What does "do not work" mean? If you post *actual* queries you're trying and *actual* error messages you're getting, you might get more constructive help.